# "The principle used to connect must have control database permission on the target database" error when doing on prem sql to azure migration

Tags: azure

I am doing onprem sql database to azure database migration from Data migration assistant and I am facing the below mentioned error when connecting to the target database. Can someone help me to resolve this.
"The principle used to connect must have control database permission on the target database"

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-azure-sql)? If yes, you can try these solutions.

**1.** [Rename the name of database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rename-a-database?view=sql-server-2017). If you have dots in the database name it does not work.Connect to master table and execute the following script on the Azure SQL Server:

USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE [my.database] Modify Name = [my-database] ;
GO

**2.** Make sure to create a firewall rule for your incoming connection. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure).

Comment: The second document doesn't even begin to tell you how to enable permissions for the azure sql server. The azure portal has 13,500 settings, but never the ones you're actually looking for. ugh.